# Pod install error after upgrading to React Native 0.63.0

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I was using React Native version `0.62.2` and now I upgrade to version `0.63.0` and after running `npx pod-install` for installing Pod packages I get this error:

> CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod “ReactCommon/callinvoker”:

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Actually, I just remove the `Podfile.lock` and delete whole the `Podfile` and add the new content from a fresh installed `React Native` project on the latest version and it means its content should be:

```
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'

platform :ios, '10.0'

target '[YourProjectName]' do
  config = use_native_modules!
  use_react_native!(:path => config["reactNativePath"])

  target '[YourProjectName]Tests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable these next few lines.
  use_flipper!
  post_install do |installer|
    flipper_post_install(installer)
  end
end

target '[YourProjectName]-tvOS' do
  # Pods for [YourProjectName]-tvOS

  target '[YourProjectName]-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end
end
```

**Note**: *it is obvious you should replace your project name with `[YourProjectName]`.*

**Hint**: *if you use manual linking, please unlink all of them, I have critical issues with manual linking of `react-native-vector-icons`*

After it, run `npx pod-install` command on the root of your project and everything will back on track.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `Podfile.lock` and Run this code on the terminal when in ios folder

```
rm -rf ./*.xcworkspace  && rm -rf ./pods && pod install
```